# ubuntu npm install lib error with node-expat build

Tags: python, node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-expat

Im trying to install office lib via npm on Ubutun 14.04. and its doesn't work. Im using Node: v4.4.0, npm: v.2.14.20 and python: v2.6.9

After running npm install office, I get the following output:

```
make: *** [Release/obj.target/node_expat/node-expat.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/apps/lsb.gorillab.co/node_modules/office/node_modul                                                          es/xml2json/node_modules/node-expat/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/                                                          node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.                                                          js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-83-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gy                                                          p/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/apps/lsb.gorillab.co/node_modules/office/node_modules/xml2json/                                                          node_modules/node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm info node-expat@2.0.0 Failed to exec install script
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-83-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-d" "office"
npm ERR! node v4.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.20
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.0.0 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm info preuninstall node-expat@2.0.0
npm info uninstall node-expat@2.0.0
npm info postuninstall node-expat@2.0.0
npm info preuninstall xml2json@0.3.2
npm info uninstall xml2json@0.3.2
npm info postuninstall xml2json@0.3.2
npm info preuninstall office@0.0.8
npm info uninstall office@0.0.8
npm info postuninstall office@0.0.8

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/apps/lsb.gorillab.co/npm-debug.log
```

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you have the necessary build environment installed (e.g. `sudo apt-get install build-essential`)?

Comment: Yep, but it still not working

Comment: Can you post the full log somewhere?

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/azuO/npm-debug.log please download this file for full log. Thank for your supporting

Comment: Is there any other text in the console that comes before what you've posted in your question (before the make error)?

Comment: http://www.megafileupload.com/6nn1/error.txt this is log on terminal

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the version of `node-expat` being installed is too old to support node v4+. A more recent version such as v2.3.13 (which is the latest as of this writing) is needed for node v4+ compatibility.

Since `node-expat` in this case is being installed as a dependency, you would need walk up the dependency tree and get each module's maintainers to update their dependencies where appropriate, starting with `xml2json` and then to `office`. In this particular case though, it seems `xml2json` is already pulling in the newer version of `node-expat` and it's `office` that needs to update its `xml2json` dependency. Unfortunately the `office` module hasn't been updated in 2 years, so you may need to fork it and update the dependency yourself if you want to use that module.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but I keep to find out the another answer, I dont know why office lib can installed on some ubuntu computer with newest node version.

Comment: The `office` module will install on older node versions such as node v0.10.x because it is depending on other older modules (namely `node-expat`) that were designed specifically for those older node versions, so that is the only way it could be working anywhere else.

Comment: Alright, I've reinstall node to v0.10 and its working now. Many thank so much dude!